# What does this sentence mean? What is the subject, predicate and object of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> “The neutral and respectful consideration **to which** Phillips was
>   entitled was compromised here,”

[source](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/04/us/politics/supreme-court-sides-with-baker-who-turned-away-gay-couple.html)
I also not too clearly understand the "to which" in this sentence.

Comment: **The neutral and respectful consideration to which Phillips was entitled** is the subject. **was compromised here** is the predicate.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, Yep, It seems clear by the split. I have thought "was entitled" and "was compromised " were paratactic (compound sentence), such as "The apple which is big and is red ... "

Comment: And, I have thought the "to" (of "to which") was connect with the "compromised". Now I know it connects with "entitled".

Comment: The sentence contains the subordinate relative clause "to which Phillips was entitled", which is modifying "consideration". The relative clause has "Philip" as subject and "consideration" as complement of "to". The relativised word is "which", whose antecedent is "consideration".